# React register form

Tags: reactjs

I have made a react register form and my problem is that I cannot write in the FirstName input. I have no problem when trying to introduce text in the lastName, Username and password. Its the same code for al of them ...

```
handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const { user } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        user: {
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}

<form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fistName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                        <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                        <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={user.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.username &&
                        <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.password &&
                        <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    {registering &&
                        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                    }
                    <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please, provide all parts needed to reproduce the problem

Comment: could you provide code of `this.handleChange` also ?

Comment: I have updated it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<input type="text" className="form-control" name="fistName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />`

Your mistake is the `name` attribute you used `fistName` instead of `firstName`

Answer (score 0):

More code details would be helpful.

Just a guess here, but since your other inputs work and they're using the same onChange, my guess is that there could be a misspelling of the state from which user.firstName is referencing

Answer (score 0):

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        user: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            username: '',
            password: ''
        },
        submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const { user } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        user: {
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    const { user } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
        dispatch(userAction.register(user));
    }
}

render() {
    const { registering } = this.props;
    const { user, submitted } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fistName" value={user.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                        <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={user.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                        <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={user.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.username &&
                        <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={user.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.password &&
                        <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    {registering &&
                        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                    }
                    <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Here's all my code!

Answer (score 0):

you're problem in your input value attribute, try to change value attribute or in onChange() function change your

```
user: {
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        }
```

change your input value attribute because you are saving your onchange input value in this.setstate so you can assign these same value in input value attribute.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        user: {
            firstName: '',
            lastName: '',
            username: '',
            password: ''
        },
        submitted: false
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
}

handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    const { user } = this.state;
    this.setState({
        user: {
            ...user,
            [name]: value
        }
    });
}

handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    const { user } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (user.firstName && user.lastName && user.username && user.password) {
        dispatch(userAction.register(user));
    }
}

render() {
    const { registering } = this.props;
    const { user, submitted } = this.state;
    return (
        <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
            <h2>Register</h2>
            <form name="form" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit} >
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.firstName ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="firstName">First Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="fistName" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.firstName &&
                        <div className="help-block">First Name is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.lastName ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="lastName" value={this.state.lastName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.lastName &&
                        <div className="help-block">Last Name is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.username ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="username">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" className="form-control" name="username" value={this.state.username} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.username &&
                        <div className="help-block">Username is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className={'form-group' + (submitted && !user.password ? 'has-error' : '')}>
                    <label htmlFor="password">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" className="form-control" name="password" value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
                    {submitted && !user.password &&
                        <div className="help-block">Password is required</div>
                    }
                </div>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <button className="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
                    {registering &&
                        <img src="data:image/gif;base64,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" />
                    }
                    <Link to="/login" className="btn btn-link">Cancel</Link>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    );
}
```